# Angular Factory & Controller best practices with ngResource

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory, ngresource

Here is my controller code for a simple app that gets, adds and deletes customers. I just watched John Papa's 2014 talk and tried to follow his style guides as best I can. I'm using node and mongo in the backend and trying to be as RESTful as I can. I'm loading the CustomersController (and using controller as syntax) in a partial. Every time I load my partial and create an instance of my controller I want to get all the customers so I can display them. I wrapped the $resource query call in a function called getAll and I just call it immediately, then I call it again inside every callback in my controller to update the list. Is this ok to do or is there another approach I need to take. For this simple app, is there anything else that I'm doing that should be avoided?

**Controller:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

angular.module('storeApp').controller('CustomersController', CustomersController);

CustomersController.$inject = ['CustomersFactory'];

/* @ngInject */
function CustomersController(CustomersFactory) {
    var vm = this;

    /* RESTful Controller functions */

    vm.getAll = function() {
        vm.customers = CustomersFactory.query(function() {
            // Do stuff after getting all the customers
        });
    };

    vm.getAll();

    vm.create = function(customer) {
        CustomersFactory.save(customer, function () {
            vm.getAll();
        });
    }

    vm.delete = function(customer) {
        customer.$delete(function() {
            vm.getAll();
        });
    };
}
})();
```

**Factory:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

angular.module('storeApp').factory('CustomersFactory', CustomersFactory);

CustomersFactory.$inject = ['$resource', '$http'];

/* @ngInject */
function CustomersFactory($resource, $http) {
    return $resource('/customers/:id', { id: '@_id'});
}

})();
```

So to summarize some of what I'm curious about:

- 1) Is creating a wrapper for getAll and calling it from within my other controller methods ok?
- 2) Is sending the whole customer object from my view/controller to the factory using the instance method of the resource $delete better than using the $resource method? Is there a RESTful/best practice way to delete a customer here without exposing the ID in the url?
- 3) Are there any other best practices I'm violating. (I know I'm not doing any error handling yet)

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start. Getting up and running with angular can be intimidating.

1. No, that's extra overhead. You have the customer list in memory already. Update the objects in the list and there's no need to retrieve them again.
2. No. The id is in the entire customer object anyway, so you're not really hiding it. You're just sending more data than is necessary.
3. It's a pretty basic start, but other than the areas you touched on, I'd say no.

Comment: If other people are doing adding and deletions, while I'm doing adding and deletions, not fetching the entire list from the DB could cause some confusion? Or is that a topic for sockets?

Comment: I thought about mentioning that as a potential reason for sticking with what you've done. I guess it really depends on scale, scope, etc. If you hope to grow the business to the point where there are a large # of customers, then retrieving the entire list at any single point in time is probably wrong. :)

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for the input! :)